# vue.js use variable value as form model name on function to manipulate input field

Tags: vue.js

I have a component with vue model , I want to set value from the component initialization function under mounted. I have some value over under mounted function in a variable. and I have the model name inside that variable. Now, how can I access that particular model? FYI the required form model name is inside the variable.

```
<template>
 <a class='btn btn-sm btn-success' @click.prevent="openModule('sort__abc','asc')"><i class="fa fa-home" ></i> </a>
        
  <select v-model="searchform['sort__abc']" class='btn-default' style='zoom:80%;' :name='"sort__abc"'>
    <option value=''>Sort</option>
    <option value='asc'>Asc</option>
    <option value='desc'>Desc</option>
  </select>
</template>
<script>
// Declare /user-management component
var cpage = 1;
export default {
  name: 'user-management',
  // Declare users (as object), form (as /vform instance) and /isFormCreateUserMode (as boolean
  // defaulted to 'true') inside /data() { return {} }.
  data() {
    return {
      //variables here
      searchform: new Form()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModule(formModel, formData) {
      //Now, I have model name on formModel and data on formData, how can i set the input value from here?
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You say you have `formModel` and `formData` inside the `openModule` method. Where is this method called from? Please include all relevant component inputs (`props`, `computed` reading from stores, etc...). Not having a *runnable* [mcve] makes it a lot more difficult to understand the problem and its context.

Comment: Its very long to include here. this function executes when button pressed and that button loads that parameters from axios

Comment: I have mentioned the entry point for openModule as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Here is my solution

```
methods: {
  openModule(formModel, formData) {
    this.searchform[formModel]=formData
  }
}
```